# add email notification to the admin of new user (WP Approve User Plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using the **Wordpress plugin 'WP Approve User'** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-approve-user/). The plugins allows a dashboard toggle to 'approve or deny' new users that sign-up for the blog; it also allows a custom email notification to be sent per 'Approval or Denial' or users..

The problem is.. and seems like a core feature for such a plugin; I would like the site admin to get a simple email notification 'New User' has signed-up and is awaiting approval.

The plugins PHP file is too large to paste here. But below is a snippet and the github link, any help would be appreciated! I simply would like to just write an an additional email notification of new-user inquiry to go to site admins email address (email address as originally intended by Wordpress > settings > general > email address..)

**https://github.com/wp-plugins/wp-approve-user/blob/master/wp-approve-user.php**

The plugin already sends emails to users that are approved or denied. I simply would like a notification to admin so they know to login and check there is a new user inquiry.

```
public function wp_authenticate_user( $userdata ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $userdata ) AND ! get_user_meta( $userdata->ID, 'wp-approve-user', true ) AND $userdata->user_email != get_bloginfo( 'admin_email' ) ) {
        $userdata = new WP_Error(
            'wpau_confirmation_error',
            __( '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Your account has to be confirmed by an administrator before you can login.', 'wp-approve-user' )
        );
    }

    return $userdata;
}
```

Comment: By default WP notifies the site admin when a new user has signed up, see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1638

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I know, but that doesn't operate anymore within implementation of this plugin. So I need a way to write it back in with custom message within plugins php file, in relation to the functionality of the plugin.

Comment: The plugin does not seem to interfere with the registration process itself. Could you explain what you mean exactly?

Comment: Well upon enabling admin no longer receives message 'New User signed up'.. I need to create this message and maintain using this plugin so the admin knows there are new pending users -- so they can go into the dashboard and utilize feature of toggle approval or denial of new user...

Comment: OK, I'll post a solution as an answer, but I think you should investigate what causes the default new user notification to malfunction. As far as I can see, it has nothing to do with the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (for some strange reason) the default new user notification does not execute, you can hook into `user_register`, which fires immediately after a new user is registered.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'so27450945_user_register', 10, 1 );
function so27450945_user_register( $user_id )
{
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES );

    $message  = sprintf( __( 'New user registration on your site %s:' ), $blogname ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s'), $user->user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf( __( 'E-mail: %s'), $user->user_email ) . "\r\n";

    @wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), sprintf( __( '[%s] New User Registration' ), $blogname ), $message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I should add this within the plugins main php file or theme's functions.php?

Comment: That's up to you. Maybe create a MU plugin? http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

Comment: Not the precise solution I was hoping for but it appears that's the best I'll get, thanks for the input @diggy #cheers